# Local Flink config running standalone from IDE

Tags: apache-flink

If I'd like to run a Flink app locally, directly from within Intellij but I need to specify config params (like fs.hdfs.hdfssite to set up S3 access), is there any other way to provide those config params apart from `ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(conf)`? What if I want to use `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment`? Can I have a Flink config in my project and point the local app to it?

Is this the proper way to do it? Or would you set up your IDE to submit the app to a real local Flink instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a `StreamExecutionEnvironment` with configuration options, use this call `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(int parallelism, Configuration configuration)`

Answer (score 4):

I could load the flink-conf.yaml file by providing the ENV_VAR ***FLINK_CONF_DIR*** in IntelliJ Run Configuration

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()` -- it will figure out the current setting and if executed in an IDE will return an "LocalEnvironemnt".

Thus, should be able to use `conf/flink-conf.yaml` to set your configuration values.

Comment: So I could put a flink-conf.yaml in my projects /src/main/resources/conf and the execution environment would find it?

Comment: Not sure... I guess `conf/flink-conf.yaml` should be in your IDE working directory.

Comment: @bibac @matthias-j-sax Can you tell me where I should put `conf/flink-conf.yaml` while running Flink job from IDEA?

Comment: @Grzes, have you find where to put it ?

Comment: The local environment does not appear to know how to load a config file. I had to manually create a `Configuration` from `ConfigurationUtils.createConfiguration` and a Properties. The environment I then created with `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(n, conf)`

Comment: I have used `createRemoteEnvironment(host, port, null)` while my flink is running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-metrics-jmx_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then change your job to use the following StreamExecutionEnvironment:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("metrics.reporter.jmx.factory.class", "org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporterFactory");
Configuration conf = ConfigurationUtils.createConfiguration(props);
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(conf);
```

If you prefer to use `createLocalEnvironment`, it works in the same way but without the Flink dashboard.

In this [blog post](https://www.galiglobal.com/blog/2021/20210130-Flink-setup.html) you can find a demo, including source code and screenshots.