# Apache Flink - set plugin folder for local development from IDE (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: apache-flink

Is it possible to override the location of Apache Flink's plugins folder to a local development environments folder in order to load them from the IntelliJ IDEAs IDE?

I tried to set the env. variable in the Run/debug configurations:

```
FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR="c:\flink-plugins\"
```

```
println("PluginsDir " + PluginConfig.getPluginsDir)
```

The output is:

```
WARN  org.apache.flink.core.plugin.PluginConfig                    [] - The plugins directory ["c:\flink-plugins\"] does not exist.
PluginsDir Optional.empty
```

Does anyone know how to load Apache Flink plugins from an IDE?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: When running locally in an IDE Flink uses a MiniCluster with LocalEnvironment or TestEnvironment (for unit tests). Unfortunately, it seems these do not utilize the local environment variables even if they are set, and there is no way to configure them otherwise.

I ran into the same problem wanting to run Flink in my IDE (VS Code) and have plugins. I used (scala) `sys.env.get(ConfigConstants.ENV_FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR)` to verify the environment variable was set correctly. Additionally, I consulted a [unit test in Flink's source](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/edac2adb9523adcb69e1dacc5fd4ea8f63480175/flink-core/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/core/plugin/PluginConfigTest.java) and found two things: First, despite setting the environment variable the value in PluginConfig was still the default. Second, overriding the value as is done in the unit test doesn't prevent the error due to plugin not found but it does change the return value of PluginConfig.getPluginsDir. This is probably because the plugins dir must be set at startup for the plugins to be found and loaded.

Looking in [Flink documenation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/dataset/local_execution/#local-environment) it appeared that the environment could be configured, but my attempt didn't work.

```scala
    val conf: Configuration = new Configuration();
    conf.setString(ConfigConstants.ENV_FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR, "C:/Users/ivwebber/Source/MDPLocal/private/MapsAI/projects/TrafficInference/Modules/traffic-forecast-pipeline/plugins/");
    
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1, conf);
```

I think the problem with this approach is that it's not a value that could be set in `conf/flink-conf.yaml`. I looked [in the source](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0915c9850d861165e283acc0f60545cd836f0567/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/ExecutionConfig.java#:%7E:text=public%20void%20configure(ReadableConfig%20configuration%2C%20ClassLoader%20classLoader)) and found that the value is never copied to the resultant config. See [here too](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/ca48138b781de0b8eb1a2589c5e5dd9450f3e13b/flink-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/ExecutionEnvironment.java#:%7E:text=config.configure(configuration%2C%20classLoader)%3B).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437011/trying-to-read-file-from-s3-with-flink-using-the-ide-getting-class-org-apache-ha#:%7E:text=For%20an%20IDE%20local%20setup%2C%20the%20root%20that,is%20necessary%20%28or%20you%20do%20it%20once%20manually%29.) may be related.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743194/local-flink-config-running-standalone-from-ide) may be related.

I probably spent more time than it's worth looking into it, so I think filing a feature request/bug would be the next step. Considering that the token "ENV_FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR" only shows up 4 times in the source; I actually wonder if its never read or used.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I think you can add the plugins as test dependencies is what I eventually found

Comment: Can confirm that adding flink-s3-fs-hadoop to the test dependencies in pom.xml worked.